# Call function when alert message is fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addeventlistener

I want to know which Dom event is fired when alert message is called. I want to call start_tracking method when alert message is called. I am able to call methods on page resize but how can i know which method is called when the alert message is fired.

```
win.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      start_tracking ();
});
```

Click event is working when i am clicking anywhere on the page but when i click the alert message content then it does not fire the click listener. Nothing seems to be fired on the `alert()` function.

Comment: The `alert` function itself does not trigger any events.

Comment: so what should i do when alert message is fired then i need to call another method @AnthonyForloney

Comment: My suggestion would be to use something more intuitive and user-friendly than the native `alert` functionality, such as jQuerys [`dialog`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) function and hook into that.

Comment: @Anthony Forloney, I couldn't agree more!

Comment: I wouldn't expect modal dialogues to impact DOM in any way.

Comment: @PM77-1 Correct, it shouldn't impact the DOM. My suggestion was more towards the notion of leveraging the ability to trigger an event when the dialog is opened (ie, through it's [`open`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open) property)

Comment: @AnthonyForloney - If OP wants to intersect his own `alert`s, then he can just wrap 'em into a function that would call something else as well. That *something* could be either hard-coded or passed as callback parameter.  If the goal is to react to `alerts` from the code that OP can't change, then your approach is not applicable.

Comment: actually it is not only about the alert i have a div content which has alert and some links so what the link is clicked or alert is pressed then it should call the method. I though 'click' should work because i am clicking on the div content but somehow it is not working

Comment: As mentioned before, I am completely with Anthony on this one. To me, it sounds completely overkill to redefine the default alert method, when there are soooo many other (and may I dare say) more elegant approaches to this, such as modal dialogs, which you can even style in harmony with the site design, whereas `.alert()` has some serious limitations in this regard.

Comment: not to mention that `alert()` blocks other script running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to capture any `alert()` function events.  I don't know why you would want to do that, but I would create another function instead called `warn()`.

```js
function warn(warning) {

  alert(warning);
  capturedAlert();

}

function capturedAlert() {

  alert('An alert was called.');

}
```

```html
<button onclick="warn('This is a warning!')">Warn!</button>
```

This way, every time `warn()` is called, you can `alert()` the user, AND call another function.

Comment: You want to because its hard to find the section of code that is causing annoying alerts in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could also override the native alert function...

```js
function testAlert(){
    alert('Test Alert Warning... You clicked a button.');
} 
window.oldAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function alert(msg){
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.name + ' is the name of the calling function.'); // calling function...
    oldAlert(msg);
    oldAlert(arguments.callee.caller.name + ' is the name of the calling function.');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testAlert();">Warn!</button>
```

This will give you the calling functions name... Hope this helps.